# Salesforce.com >> Validation is not working correctly. Scenario is explained via an example

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, salesforce-id

I have a validation rule which restricts all users from creating a NEW account. But selected users from 2 profiles are allowed to create a NEW account. So I am making use of "Custom Permission" and I have a permission set which includes this Custom Permission. So, in turn, I am making use of this "Custom Permission" in my validation rule.

`AND(NOT($Permission.Bypass_AccountCreationValidation),ISNEW())`
"**Error: Access denied. You are not allowed to create a NEW account.**"

So all user who is not assigned to this permission set gets restricted to create a NEW account but this validation only works for the users from one profile whereas all other users from other profile are able to create a NEW account.

For example, Profile A and Profile B are 2 profiles.
User 1 from Profile A and User 2 from Profile B are the only 2 users who are allowed to create a new account.
User 1 and User 2 are able to create a new account via Permission Set PS1. I have created custom permission named "Bypass_AccountCreationValidation" which is added to PS1.

Scenario A] While testing if I log as User 1 from Profile A OR User 2 from Profile B then I am able to create an account. This is correct as I want to bypass the validation for these 2 users.

Scenario B] If I log as User 3 from Profile A then I am getting "Error: Access denied. You are not allowed to create a NEW account." This is correct as ONLY User 1 from Profile A is allowed to create a new account.

**Scenario C] But I log as User 4 from Profile B then I am not getting any error and User 4 is able to create a new account. This is incorrect as ONLY User 2 from Profile B is allowed.**
What is going wrong here?

Comment: Did you accidentally add the custom permission to the profile as well as the permission set?

Comment: Nope...I've not Enabled Custom Permissions at the profile level. As per your response to my last post I've created custom permission and added it to Permission set like following this example then only to PS1. I want to know what is the extra privileges with which Salesforce.com users can create NEW records. Any thought?

Comment: Hey....this is resolved for now! I noticed that in this existing rule, Profile B is also mentioned which is wrong. So it was something like - `AND($Profile.Name <> "Profile B",NOT($Permission.Bypass_AccountCreationValidation),ISNEW())` which I missed to notice. I removed $Profile.Name <> "Profile B" from this validation rule and everything is now working as expected. Again thank you @PhilW as your question helped me to dig more into this configuration.

Comment: No worries. I suggest you add the explanation as your own question answer so we can get this closed off.

Comment: Not sure how to do this but as per your suggestion I would like to add this comment that the issue is RESOLVED and can get mark as RESOLVED/CLOSED. Thank you!

Comment: You should see an "Answer your question" button at the bottom of the page which you can use to provide an answer rather than comment. Please use this to add explanation of the issue resolution.

Comment: Super....you are a pro! Thank you @PhilW again :-)

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that in this existing rule, Profile B is also mentioned which is wrong. So it was something like - `AND($Profile.Name <> "Profile B",NOT($Permission.Bypass_AccountCreationValidation),ISNEW())` which I missed to notice. I removed $Profile.Name <> "Profile B" from this validation rule and everything is now working as expected.